# Generating guitar chords image in Android SDK

Tags: android, sdk, guitar, music-notation

Is there any way to generate images of guitar chords in Android SDK or do I need to create image in Photoshop etc. for every chord?

Comment: Please clarify the question - do you want to create images of vibrating strings of different thicknesses, or do you mean musical notations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [`Canvas`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) class. It allows you to draw images programatically.
This way you could replicate the fretboard with an x-number of frets and strings and of course the positions of the chords related to the fretboard.
I'd imagine you make a draw function for the fretboard and a draw function for different types of chords.

Have fun!